# What statements do you not write in vb.net because they are difficult to scan for meaning? And what do you write instead?

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

This should be a community wiki question.

I've had to work with a lot of vb.net lately, and recently created the following expression.

```
If If(report.IsPublicReport, False) Then Return True
```

Now, this is a simple coalesce inside of an if statement, nothing to be scared of.  However, when I was scanning the method looking for an error I had made, this line would constantly stop me dead in my tracks.  I just couldn't scan it.  Every time I had to stop and break it down manually in my head.  Largely because I had to stop and figure out what each `If` was actually doing in the expression.

I have since rewritten the line as

```
If report.IsPublicReport.GetValueOrDefault() Then Return True
```

While more verbose, I am finding that this disrupts my train of thought less as I am scanning the code.

This got me thinking,

1. Is this something other more experienced
   VB.net developers are running into?
2. Are there any other types of
   expressions that are largely
   avoided, or at least not favored?
3. Am I just whining about nothing?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are uncomfortable with VB.NET syntax, I would *strongly* recommend you use Option Strict On so you catch mistakes like these quicker.  The best way is by changing it globally so it is always on by default.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VB Defaults, change Option Strict to "On".

Comment: +1 @Matthew What is the type of `report.IsPublicReport`? If it is `Boolean` then why do you need the `If` at all?! If it is *not* Boolean, then you should be explicitly converting, and `Option Strict` will remind you about that.

Comment: IsPublicReport is a nullable boolean

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is something Scott Hanselman (and probably others) call "Code smell".

It's basically the idea that when you look at a piece of code and something doesn't seem "right" about it. This is not a capability that developers just "have". It's something you develop over time as you read and write more and more code.

It's not just VB either, you'll see plenty of idiomatic constructs in every language that will (or should) make you pause and question what you're looking at.

That Double IF would definitely do it for me

Comment: Hans's comment about Option strict is definitely a good idea. I turn it on ALWAYS unless I have a specific module or class where I need it turned off, which is pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

In Vb.NET you can write:

```
row!FirstName = "Test"
```

instead of

```
row("FirstName") = "Test"
```

A while ago I used to write `row!FirstName` (you can do that with every item in a collection that can be accessed by a string parameter) because I thought that was a good idea because it looks more statically typed (like `person.FirstName` as a property) and is shorter.

However I realized that this is not a good idea because after changing "FirstName" to "Name" i often looked for String in the current file which are highlited in Visual Studio (the object!param syntax is not).
Which makes finding them harder.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

```
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
```

instead of

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
```

which is fine if you don't need sender or e (I suppose it is just some compiler magic that adds the signature itself) but I refuse to use the shorter way, cause you don't recognize it as an eventhandler at first sight.

Comment: Now that's +wierd+. Just tried it and it does work. What's odd is if you include, say, just the sender arg, it won't compile (says its not the right number of arguments?!). So I guess the vb.net authors decided that 0=2, but 1<>2 <g>. This just became the weirdest thing I've seen all day...

Comment: That's a feature of VB 9 called relaxed delegates.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364068%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vb9overview_topic10

Comment: I think VB 10 further relaxed this.  See secion 9.2.6 in the VB spec.